# Magento 2 : Store credit does not deducted on reorder from admin

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, store-credit

- **Issue** : **When we reorder from admin, & pay using customer store credit balance then order gets placed but store credit doesn't get deducted.**

Using `Magento/2.4 (Enterprise)`

Steps to replicate error

1. Issue store credit in M2 via credit memo.
2. Go to customer’s account in M2
3. Click reorder
4. Add or update item if necessary
5. Edit prices if necessary
6. Edit addresses if necessary
7. Select Store Credit as payment method and select shipping method
8. Click submit order

Then if you look at the customer’s account the store credit did not get auto-deducted.

I have checked class

```
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Save.php
```

But i did not found any code here that deduct store credit for order when order paid using customer store credit.

Any thoughts on this please ?

Comment: Customer balance is not adjusted on reorder

Comment: Any thoughts on this please ?